# How to migrate B2B store from sandbox to production?

Tags: deployment, b2b-commerce, steelbrick, b2b

Does anyone have an idea deploying b2b store configuration and components from sandbox to production?

If you provide a document or any procedural steps that could be more useful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.comm_migrate_store.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

You can do it with change sets

1.Export the store that you want to migrate.
From the store’s home page, select Administration | General Settings.
In the Store Migration section, under Export Store Configuration, click Export.

2.Create an outbound change set.
In Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter change sets, and select Outbound Change Sets.
Click Continue, and then click New.
Add a name and description for your change set, and click Save.
Under Change Set Components, click Add.
For Component Type, select Site.com.
Select the store that you want to migrate, and click Add to Change Set.
Click Add, and for Component Type, select Store Configuration.
Make sure that your store is still selected, and click Add Change Set.

3.Apply the store configuration to a new environment.
Go to the environment where you want to migrate the store configuration.
In Setup, navigate back to Change Sets, and select Inbound Change Sets.
Click Continue, select the change set that you created, and click Deploy.
Navigate to the Commerce app navigation menu, and select Store | Administration | General Settings.
Under Apply Store Configuration, click Apply.
Select the store configuration, and click Apply.

Comment: Welcome to the site Toby - could you list the bassic steps here? Links (even Salesforce docs ones ;)) tend to break over time so to ensure this answer stays useful it'd be good to add the basics. That'd increase your odds of some upvotes!